# How To Scan a Page For Terms And Display Them - Javascript - Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying at the moment to make a google chrome extension and have hit a roadblock.

I want the extension to scan the page for 3 terms and display them in a div, but I do not have much knowledge in JavaScript and need help.

Comment: Are you looking to scan the HTML DOM for 3 specific terms? Is that what you mean?

Comment: For example say I want to scan the comments of this post and see how many times: the, to and from are typed and display the amount of time’s they show up like: the 2, to 4, and from 0

Comment: Okay it's possible and I know how to do it, but you might require some special permissions from Chrome Extension use for this, so don't forget to add the scope of permission in the manifest.json file. Also assuming now, that you have access to the dom of the website, I will post the answer on how to search for parituclr words and how to display the count of the same. Will that be okay? @derpyranbowpop

Comment: Yes that would be great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const globalWordsStore = new Map();
const setOfWords = ['Hello', 'World']
function populateStore(el){
  let n;
  let a=[];
  let walk=document.createTreeWalker(el,NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT,null,false);
  while(n=walk.nextNode()) {
    const arrayOfWords = n.data.trim().split(" ");
    arrayOfWords.forEach((ele) => {
      if(setOfWords.includes(ele)){
        if(globalWordsStore.has(ele)){
        globalWordsStore.set(ele, globalWordsStore.get(ele) + 1);
      } else {
        globalWordsStore.set(ele, 1);
      }
      }
    })
  }
}

populateStore(document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]);

for (const [key, value] of globalWordsStore.entries()) {
  // key --> word
  // value --> count of that partivular word
  console.log(key, value);
}
```

Here Map will be storing all the words and their count. Here the approach is, to first pick out all the text nodes from the DOM (which are a child of the body element), then extract the text from it, next I created an array using words in the entire text and then used `globalWordsStore` to the store of occurrence of each individual word and this I did for all the text nodes in the DOM.

More about [CreateTreeWalker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createTreeWalker)

Comment: Let me know if you need anything else :), hope it helps!

Comment: Where am i ment to put the words @Nikhil Singh

Comment: In your `script` file of your chrome extension

Comment: Or if you want to test, put this at the bottom of any HTML file inside script tag and it will work

Comment: Ive put the code in my extention and its working i think. in the dev console i can see output from the code but how do i find what i want. so in the code what do i do to make it look for a set word

Comment: Do you want to know the count of specific word, or set of words ?

Comment: I need a set of words